# Accessing the image source changed dynamically

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some images and code like this, which changes the large-image when a thumb is clicked.:

image-01-thumb.jpg
image-01-full.jpg
image-02-thumb.jpg
image-02-full.jpg

```
$.each($('img'), function () {
    if ($(this).attr('src').toString().indexOf('thumb.jpg') > -1) {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $('.large-image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'full'));
        });
    }
});
```

But when I try to access the src of the image to apply the effects of some plugin, the DOM isn't updated and I access always the original src:

```
$(document).on('click', '.large-image', function () {
    $('.large-image').pluginEffect();
});
```

When I change the image src dinamically to image-02-full.jpg, it still applys the effect to image-01-full.jpg

How can I access the updated src or how can I refresh the DOM?

Comment: Of topic: Your whole `each` and `if` code could be simplified to this: `$('img[src$="thumb.jpg"]').click(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing the plugin on all elements with the `large-image` class, and the plugin may be only acting on the first one. Do this to target only the clicked element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.large-image', function () {
    $(this).pluginEffect();
});
```

Comment: I should have used an id, but anyway there is only 1 large-image element. What I realised is that it only applys not necessarily to the original one but only to the first I used pluginEffect() on. Could be that the plugin caches the image's source?

Comment: Could be, or could be that you need to destroy the plugin instance before calling it again.

Comment: Do you know how could I destroy the plugin if it only has a public init function but not a destroy one?

Comment: Sure. Did that fix everything?